# For each loop with regex

Tags: r, regression, lm

I have a dataset like this :

```
y_post = c(0,1,2,3) 
y_pre = c(0,1,5,3) 
x_post = c(0,1,4,3) 
x_pre = c(0,1,4,3) 
x_time_pre = c(0,4,2,3) 
x_time_post = c(0,4,2,3) 
y_time_pre = c(0,1,5,3) 
y_time_post = c(0,1,4,3)
strata = c(1,2,2,1)
df = data.frame(strata, y_post, y_pre, x_post, x_pre,x_time_pre,x_time_post, y_time_pre, y_time_post)
```

What I want to do, is create a loop to run regression for each variable that contains the word "time" in it such that

```
fit <- lm(var_contains_"time"_post ~ same_var_contains_"time"_pre +strata)
```

I am not really sure how I can specify that?
For example i want to run

```
lm (y_time_post ~y_time_pre+strata)
```

and do that for all the variables (i have 20) which have the word time in them

Answer (score 0):

We can create the vectorr of column names that shows 'time_pre', 'time_post' and use `Map` to loop over the corresponding elements, create the formula with `reformulate` and apply `lm`

```
nm1 <- grep('time_pre', names(df), value = TRUE)
nm2 <- grep('time_post', names(df), value = TRUE)

Map(function(x, y) lm(reformulate(c(x, 'strata'), 
          response = y), data = df), nm1, nm2)
```

-output

```
#$x_time_pre

#Call:
#lm(formula = reformulate(c(x, "strata"), response = y), data = df)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)   x_time_pre       strata  
#  4.441e-16    1.000e+00    0.000e+00  


#$y_time_pre

#Call:
#lm(formula = reformulate(c(x, "strata"), response = y), data = df)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)   y_time_pre       strata  
#       0.50         0.84        -0.26
```

---

To extract the coefficients

```
library(broom)
do.call(rbind, Map(function(x, y) tidy(lm(reformulate(c(x, 'strata'), 
          response = y)), data = df), nm1, nm2))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
#  term         estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#* <chr>           <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 (Intercept)  4.44e-16     0       Inf       0     
#2 x_time_pre   1.00e+ 0     0       Inf       0     
#3 strata       0.           0       NaN     NaN     
#4 (Intercept)  5.00e- 1     0.671     0.745   0.592 
#5 y_time_pre   8.40e- 1     0.12      7.00    0.0903
#6 strata      -2.60e- 1     0.461    -0.564   0.673
```

---

If the column names are different, use `bind_rows` or `map2_dfr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map2_dfr(nm1, nm2, ~ tidy(lm(reformulate(c(.x, 'strata'), 
       response = .y), data = df)))
```

Comment: thank you but this unfortunately does not store the coefficient and the standard error.. i tried putting it onto a list but it just generate a huge list, do you know how i can improve ? @akrun

Comment: @Lola1993  If you need to extract all the coefficient,, use `tidy` from `broom`

Comment: unfortunately it did not work! i get returned an error saying "Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : 
  object 'fox_cnn_time_wave_4' not found" even though i clearly see this var in my data and your previous formula (without rbind) worked!!! so im confused